# Duplicating file type in pyCharm

Tags: pycharm, application-settings

I have added a new file extension for a C dialect and would like to add a new keyword. However, if the file is associated with C/C++ adding new keywords would add them to all C/C++ files.

Creating new file type is and obvious option, but manually re-entering all C keywords is too laborious. There should be some a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the simplest way is to edit language that is extended which will create a file in filetypes/ (in directory @yole has mentioned). For example, for A C/C++ A *C__.xml* file will be created. **Import is to register at least one extension with that file type!** Only then, the file is created.

Add new file type and register *real* extension.
Copy keywords from *C__.xml* to *Your file type*.

Clean up extensions and keywords from original file type.

Restart.

thanks @yole for pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to edit the .xml configuration files directly. Add your keyword to the C/C++ filetype, then edit `options/filetypes.xml` under the PyCharm application settings directory (`~/.PyCharm##` on Win/Linux, `~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm##` on Mac) and copy the block for C/C++ to your new extension. Then restart PyCharm and remove the extra keyword in the C/C++ filetype definition.

Comment: the only thing that appeared was  <mapping ext="mine" type="C++" /> and there were no keywords in that file. I am using 4.0.6 version.

Comment: I found the solution, it was a bit more complicated, thanks for the pointer to the right direction.